# Making this recursive fibonacci with memoization even faster?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, memoization

Is there a way to make this program run faster? It is already faster than a HashMap version I tried making, but it's still too slow around the 45 mark, according to where I'm submitting it to. Is there any modification I could do to improve it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibo {
    static long[] cache;
    static long ans;

    public static long fibo(int n) {
        if (n == 0) 
            return 1;
        if (n < 2) 
            ans = 1;
        else
            ans = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
        cache[n - 1] = ans;
        return ans;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("test");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            input.close();
            cache = new long[num];
            long ans = fibo(num);
            System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: you never actually perform any lookup in `cache` or am I missing something?

Comment: Fibo() is only called once from your main method, the cache is never really used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to memoize answers in your cache, but you aren't utilizing it. Check your cache before any other calculations.  Also, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you get to `fibo(0)` because you're subtracting one.  Remove the subtraction and increase the size of your array to account for it.

```
public static long fibo(int n) {
    // Try cache first.
    if (cache[n] != 0) return cache[n];
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (n < 2) 
        ans = 1;
    else
        ans = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
    // Don't subtract one.
    cache[n] = ans;
    return ans;
}
```

In main, make room for the answer to `fibo(num)`.

```
cache = new long[num + 1];
```

Comment: Maybe OP deliberately didn't save for `n=0`, and saved at `n-1`, so the array would only need to be created with size `num`. Your code would only get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you changed the index position of the save.

Comment: @Andreas When creating my solution, I added the line to use the cache at the top of the method first.  I _did_ get an AIOOBE, because eventually `fibo(0)` will get called.  Therefore, the "minus one" to save one space in the array was incorrect.  An alternative would be to check the cache _after_ the base case(s).

Comment: So *your* error was that you added cache check *before* the `n==0` check, and decided to fix in a way that required more changes, rather than just flipping the checks.

Comment: @Andreas I decided to fix the code in a way that is more understandable and readable.  My goal here wasn't to fix the code in the least number of changes possible, but to fix the code in the most understandable, readable way.  To me, it makes more sense to have the index of the array `i` store `fibo(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it faster by actually *using* the cached values:

```
public static long fibo(int n) {
    if (cache[n] > 0) {
        return cache[n];
    }
    ...
    cache[n] = ans; // you are saving at the wrong index
    ...
}
```

Although using memoization is "fast" at O(n), there's a mathy O(log n) solution that super fast.

Comment: Why is OP saving to the wrong index? OP is never saving for `n=0`, so saving at `n-1` is valid, and fits the fact that array was only create with size `num`.

Comment: @Andreas because it's clearer, obvious and fits the general memoization pattern of saving the value at `cache[parameter]` not `cache[some other value that may save a whopping 8 bytes of memory]`

Comment: But saving at `n-1` is not "wrong". Non-standard, maybe. Less optimal, perhaps. But not *wrong*.

Comment: @Andrea at code review time I would definitely say it is wrong, because it's making comprehension and debugging more difficult for no gain whatsoever